# How to identify the fields having default values when deserialized using jackson

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I have a class `Person` and I want to deserialize a POJO from a JSON using jackson. Now,
the definition to `Person` class is something like :

```
class Person {
   int id;
   String name;
   boolean isOldAge;
   boolean hasSenseOfHumor;
   .
   .
   .
}
```

Now my json is something like :

```
   {
   "id" : 1,
   "isOldAge" : false
   }
```

Now when I deserialize this into a POJO the values I will get would be :

```
[id=1,name="",isOldAge=false,hasSenseOfHumor=false]
```

i.e, the properties not mentioned in json will be assigned their default values.

So my problem lies here. Is there a way I can distinguish `isOldAge` from `hasSenseOfHumor` with respect to whether it is mentioned or provided for by the user or not.

Comment: @Stackoverflow : No response? :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the primitive `boolean` to the boxing `Boolean` type. The fields should be initialised with `null` values then.

If you cannot change field types of the class, then can read your JSON as map in advance as follows `mapper.readValue(JSON, Map.class)`, and then reason about the presence of the boolean fields in the resulting map instance.

Comment: @Alexety : I could have done that but let's say the class wasn't generated by me ... I get a class that has been provided by someone else and it's his wish to use boolean and not Boolean. Can I change the property of the class by creating an on-the-fly class where I can change the primitives to wrapper.

Comment: @Sourabh I have updated my answer with regards to this. I think if you want to get the information about whether the field is present or not is to read your JSON as map.

Comment: I have been using the same. It becomes a bit of developers responsibility. Thus, I was wondering whether ObjectMapper has any set annotations or enables us to fill in an adapter or function to an event while serializing or deserializing.